Nonstandard way to prove the limit of the partial average of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit
I am trying to prove by nonstandard analysis a well known theorem: If $\{a_n\}_n$ converge to to $L$, then its partial average sequence $\{\overline a_n\}_n$, with $\overline a_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, converge to the same limit $L$. Is there a good way to do it?
Up to now, the only result I can get is that $\bar a_N$ is a finite hyperreal for hypernatural numbers; and also, if $N$ is not finite, then $a_M$ for $M$ in the same galaxy of $N$ has the same standard part as $a_N$.

$
\newcommand\near[1]{\mathchoice{\underset{#1}\approx}{\approx_{#1}}{\approx_{#1}}{\approx_{#1}}}
\newcommand\st{\mathrm{st}}
$Since $a_i$ converges to $L$, by definition $a_\omega\approx L$ for any infinite $\omega$.
I will use the fact that $\bar a_\omega$ is finite for all infinite $\omega$, as you claim to have proven.
For every standard $\epsilon>0$ there are finitely many standard $i$ such that $|a_i-L|\geq\epsilon$; otherwise by overspill there is an infinite $\omega$ with $|a_\omega-L|\geq\epsilon$, which is impossible because $a_\omega\approx L$. Let $N$ be the largest such $i$. Let
$$
  \bar a_n' = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^Na_i,\quad \bar a_n'' = \frac1n\sum_{i=N+1}^na_i.
$$
Of course $\bar a_n = \bar a'_n + \bar a''_n$. Now choose $n = \omega$ infinite. Then $\bar a'_\omega\approx 0$, and
$$
  \bar a_\omega - L \approx \bar a''_\omega - L = \sum_{i=N+1}^\omega\left(\frac{a_i}\omega - \frac L{\omega - N}\right) = \sum_{i=N+1}^\omega\frac{(\omega - N)a_i - \omega L}{\omega(\omega-N)} = \frac1{\omega-N}\sum_{i=N+1}^\omega(a_i-L) - \frac N{\omega(\omega-N)}\sum_{i=N+1}^\omega a_i = \frac1{\omega-N}\sum_{i=N+1}^\omega(a_i-L) - \frac {\bar a''_\omega}{\omega-N} \approx \frac1{\omega-N}\sum_{i=N+1}^\omega(a_i-L).
$$
The last approximation comes from $\bar a_\omega$ being finite. Finally,
$$
  |\bar a_\omega - L| \lesssim \frac1{\omega-N}\sum_{i=N+1}^\omega|a_i-L| < \epsilon
$$
for all standard $\epsilon$, so $\bar a_\omega\approx L$. By $x\lesssim y$ we mean that there is an infinitesimal $\iota$ such that $x\leq\iota+y$.

I found this problem (with solution) as Exercise 58 in Analysis with Ultrasmall Numbers by Hrbacek, Lessmann, and O'Donavan. (Highly recommended!) This book makes use of an axiomatic version of nonstandard analysis with infinitely many levels of relative nonstandardness. Their proof seems to make essential use of this (more specifically of two levels of nonstandardness). I will use different notation and terminology than they use so that is is more inline with typical nonstandard analysis.
To first approximation, this theory is like Nelson's Internal Set Theory except you need to specify standardness relative to other objects. I will write $\st(x;y)$ for "$x$ is standard relative to $y$" or equivalently "$x$ is $y$-standard". We will use $\st(x;y_1,\dotsc,y_k)$ as a shorthand for $\st(x;(y_1,\dotsc,y_k))$ which is equivalent to $\st(x;y_1)\lor\dotsb\lor\st(x; y_k)$. We will use the abbreviations
$$
  \forall^{\st(y_1,\dotsc,y_k)}x.\phi \;\equiv\; \forall x.\:\st(x;y_1,\dotsc,y_k)\implies\phi,
$$$$
  \exists^{\st(y_1,\dotsc,y_k)}x.\phi \;\equiv\; \exists x.\:\st(x;y_1,\dotsc,y_k)\land\phi.
$$
Finally, I will also write
$$
  x \near{y_1,\dotsc,y_k} z \;\equiv\; \forall^{\st(y_1,\dotsc,y_k)}\alpha\in\mathbb R_+.\:|x-z|<\alpha,
$$
for being $(y_1,\dotsc,y_k)$-infinitesimal, and
$$
  x \near{y_1,\dotsc,y_k} \infty \;\equiv\; \forall^{\st(y_1,\dotsc,y_k)}\alpha\in\mathbb R_+.\:|x|>\alpha
$$
for being $(y_1,\dotsc,y_k)$-infinite.
Now fix $M,N\in\mathbb N$ such that $M\near a\infty$ and $N\near{a,M}\infty$. That $a$ converges to $L$ means that $\st(L;a)$ and that $a_i\near a L$ for all $i\near a\infty$, so for any such $i$ there is an $\epsilon_i\near a0$ such that $a_i = L + \epsilon_i$. Now
$$
  \bar a_N = \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Ma_i + \frac1N\sum_{i=M+1}^Na_i.
$$
The first term is $\near{a,M}0$ since the sum is $(a,M)$-standard and $N$ is $(a,M)$-infinite. For the second term,
$$
  \frac1N\sum_{i=M+1}^Na_i = L - \frac MNL + \frac1N\sum_{i=M+1}^N\epsilon_i.
$$
For the second term, $\frac MNL\near{a,M}0$. If $\epsilon = \max_{M+1\leq i\leq N}|\epsilon_i|$, then the third term is bounded in absolute value by
$$
  \frac{N-M}N\epsilon = \epsilon - \frac MN\epsilon \near{a} 0
$$
where $\epsilon\near{a}0$ and $M\epsilon/N\near{a,M}0$.
In summary,
$$
  \bar a_N
  \quad=\quad \underbrace{\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Ma_i}_{\near{a,M}0} + L - \underbrace{\frac MNL}_{\near{a,M}0} + \underbrace{\frac1N\sum_{i=M+1}^N\epsilon_i}_{\near{a}0}
  \quad\near{a}\quad L.
$$
We are not done yet; we proved for all $(a,M)$-infinite $N\in\mathbb N$ that $\bar a_N\near aL$, but we need to prove this for all $a$-infinite $N$. Being $(a,M)$-infinite is too large and misses the smaller $a$-infinite naturals. Right here is where we make essential use of relativized nonstandard analysis; the trick is to write this statement out
$$
  \forall^{\st(a,M)}N\in\mathbb N.\:\forall^{\st(a)}\alpha>0.\:|\bar a_N-L|<\alpha
$$
and note that we can fix $\alpha$ to get
$$
  \forall^{\st(a,M)}N\in\mathbb N.\:|\bar a_N-L|<\alpha.
$$
All parameters of this statement are $a$-standard, and it is of a form amenable to Transfer, yielding
$$
  \forall^{\st(a)}N\in\mathbb N.\:|\bar a_N-L|<\alpha
$$
for all $a$-standard $\alpha$, and this is equivalent to $\bar a_N\near{a}L$ for all $a$-infinite $N$, as desired.

I don't like using this kind of $\epsilon$ in nonstandard proof, but I'm struggling to find an alternative. The issue, as I see it, is that we can easily control the terms $a_i$ with $i\leq N$ standard; and we can easily control the terms with $i\geq\omega$ infinite; but how do we control the terms in the "transition" $N<i<\omega$?
